# Can I ask about finding a substitute / replacement component that's discontinued?

Tags: discussion

I am following an old schematic and a few of the Inductors are discontinued and cannot be found for sale anywhere. I have the datasheets but don't know enough about Inductors to find a suitable substitute.

The rules specifically state shopping type recommendations are off-topic, so I'm wondering if my question is in a grey-area.

Comment: I've found a few related questions, but they date back to 2011. The consensus there seems to be that these types of questions can be allowed, in some circumstances:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, I think it's a good question if you emphasize this part:

> don't know enough about Inductors to find a suitable substitute

An answer to that will be valuable far longer than a simple shopping question.

Comment: Good point, I could phrase my question so I'm asking how I could go about finding it myself